# Python 3 - Limiting Memory Usage from a Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using the itertools module to create a list of possible permutations for the order of letters in a rather long sentence. However, every time I do so I run out of memory (I have 16GB RAM before anyone asks).

I don't have the code on this machine, however it is not inefficient code since it is a carbon copy of one of the examples in the documentation, there are simply too many permutations which Python is trying to do all at once.

The questions is, is there a way of limiting the amount of memory that Python uses, maybe by giving it a pool? I know I should probably change the code, but I would benefit from a pool of memory for other projects as well.

I cannot use the Theano module because I am using Conda, which is incompatible. I have tried the gc module with little effect, but again, the code is an example, and the sentence is about a dozen characters, printing the list on screen.

**Edit:**

Here's the main section of my code. *I do not suggest running it* since it causes my machine to crash.

```
import itertools
f = open('File.txt','w')
for key, value in dict.items():
    print(list(itertools.permutations((str(counter-value)))),file=f)
```

The dict variable is a 76 element dictionary containing different characters which the code checks. The actual function of the code is complicated and fits into a hundred or so line script, but this is the point that I'm having problems with. If the code works, it should be calculation literally millions of permutations. My problem is that it tries to do them all at once. I want to know if there is some way I can limit it, even if it means the code will run slower.

Comment: "it is not inefficient code since it is a carbon copy of one of the examples in the documentation" - that doesn't make it efficient code. Iterating over permutations at all is only ever a good idea for extremely short inputs. Use an algorithm that doesn't do that.

Comment: While limiting the memory usage is possible, it just means you'll crash with a `MemoryError` sooner rather than later.

Comment: The general use case of hitting a `MemoryError` may still be preferable to consuming more RAM on a machine.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't made it clear, I am not hitting any MemoryError. I have Task Manager open at the side telling me the resources that are being used, and when the programme is running the graph is about to go to 100% before the whole computer freezes due to lack of memory. I appreciate that my code will not be efficient, but I want a slow down.

Comment: @Master-chip do you want it to just print the elements in the list?

Comment: Please just post your code or the example page so we don't have to guess what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop over the permutations and write each of them to the file, like this:

```
import itertools
f = open('File.txt','w')
for key, value in dict.items():
    for i in itertools.permutations((str(counter-value))):
        print(i, file=f)
```

As it is a generator, the items are retrieved one-by-one so your memory won't be exhausted.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.